# Maven: no coverage when combining 2 profiles

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a maven build with 2 relevant profiled called integration-build (to run integration tests) and sonar (for coverage).

- The integration build without coverage works
- the normal build without integration tests + coverage in sonar works (coverage appears in sonarqube)
- the integration build with coverage does not work (coverage is 0)

So the last type of build fails. My command is:

```
mvn clean install -Pintegration-build,sonar
```

This seems the relevant part in my integration-build maven profile:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx2048m</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx2048m</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/IT*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And this is my sonar profile:

```
<profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    <properties>
        <envTarget>tst</envTarget>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>@{surefire.argLine} -Xms256m -Xmx2048m</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>@{failsafe.argLine} -Xms256m -Xmx2048m</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/IT*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyName>surefire.argLine</propertyName>
                            <destFile>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-it-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyName>failsafe.argLine</propertyName>
                            <destFile>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-it-test</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report-aggregate</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <createChecksum>true</createChecksum>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Now I updated these lines in my integration-build profile:
`<argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx2048m</argLine>` to `<argLine>@{surefire.argLine} -Xms256m -Xmx2048m</argLine>`
and
`<argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx2048m</argLine>` to `<argLine>@{failsafe.argLine} -Xms256m -Xmx2048m</argLine>`

Then it works. after his I run mvn sonar:sonar -Psonar and I get integration tests and coverage.

But when I now run just with only the integration-build profile (without sonar) then it fails!
Then I get errors like:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project app-models: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /srv/path//build/build-IB/app-models/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd "/srv/autobuild/workspace/build/build-IB/app-models" && /srv/path/tools/hudson.model.JDK/IBM-JDK8-x86_64/jre/bin/java '@{surefire.argLine}' -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -jar '/srv/autobuild/workspace/build/build-IB/app-models/target/surefire/surefirebooter6984324204710827506.jar' '/srv/autobuild/workspace/build/build-IB/app-models/target/surefire' 2020-03-20T11-00-50_881-jvmRun1 surefire5755643707151660451tmp surefire_04579178873474557152tmp
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd "/srv/path/workspace/build/build-IB/app-models" && /srv/path/tools/hudson.model.JDK/IBM-JDK8-x86_64/jre/bin/java '@{surefire.argLine}' -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -jar '/srv/path/workspace/build/build-IB/app-models/target/surefire/surefirebooter6984324204710827506.jar' '/srv/path/workspace/build/build-IB/app-models/target/surefire' 2020-03-20T11-00-50_881-jvmRun1 surefire5755643707151660451tmp surefire_04579178873474557152tmp
```

How can I fix this but keep my coverage?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that you put `<configuration>` in the failsafe and surefire plugin that is not compatible when you have both profiles activated.

Remember that profiles are merged when you activate them. So you suddenly have two `<argLine>` definitions etc.

I guess you need to move as much as possible of the `<configuration>` into the `<execution>` that needs it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. So I should exclude the -Xms256m -Xmx2048m part from the argline in my integration-build configuration and adding it as argline to the execution part?

Comment: I would try that.

Comment: I tried it. The build with 2 profiles activated works (with coverage), but the build with only the integration-profile activated without sonar activated fails on Error '@{surefire.argLine}'. In my current setup the config for it is <argLine>@{surefire.argLine}</argLine> and the config in the execution is <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx2048m</argLine>

Comment: It seems it get merged well when I use both profiles, but when I don't use the sonar profile it seems that the integration-build profile can not resovle the @{surefire.argLine} or am I wrong?